# Nativescript code signing without Sidekick

Tags: ios, iphone, nativescript

I'm trying to run my app on my iPhone 7 Plus but I get the following error:

```
Unable to apply changes on device: 0bc71c109e65b10a62a6f57229e57e840c8bf3d5. Error is: Cannot read property 'Type' of null.
```

In looking closer to the output I see this which makes me think I need to code sign the app:

```
... isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.
```

Is there some way to do that with NativeScript?  All of the documentation I can find seems to be in relation to Sidekick which I don't want to use.

Comment: May I know what exactly you are trying to do in your project? If you are using any feature that requires entitlements, you must have a paid apple subscription and set it up. There is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to specifically provide the `--device` and `--provision` flags when running:

```
tns run ios --device my-device-id --provision my-provision-profile-id
```